# the jqueryui datepicker "create" of event don't work

Tags: jquery-ui, events, datepicker

In my project which uses with jQueryUI's datepicker of plugins,

but in this code, the "create" event never fires,

you can check the documentation in official site: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-showOptions

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({
    create: function(event, ui) {
        alert("ppp");
    }
});
```

Comment: wich version of jQuery and jQuery UI are you using??

Comment: jQuery1.7   and   jQuery UI-1.8.16

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to achieve this with the jQuery UI Datepicker because no such event is simply triggered.

The documentation of jQuery UI is sometimes a bit falsy. My opinion is that the authors rely on the fact that all plugins are using the [Widget Factory](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138135/Widget%20factory) but this is actually not the case for the datepicker !

For plugins thats uses the Widget factory, the event "create" is automatically triggered during the creation of the Widget:

```
_createWidget: function( options, element ) {
    // some other code
    // ...    
    this._create();
    this._trigger( "create" );
    this._init();
},
```

Unfortunately, neither the datepicker implements the Widget factory (this [planned](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137778/Datepicker) though) nor it triggers a "create" event explicitely ([source](https://raw.github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/master/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js)).

Didier.

Comment: I guess so since the rework of Datepicker is planned for release 1.13 ([roadmap](http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138038/Roadmap))

Answer (score 1):

There is no event for create in date picker plugin in Jquery ui. You can use:

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker({ 
    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
        create(); 
    } 
}); 
function create() { 
    alert("ppp"); 
}
```